# Display an int number in notification bar icon Android

Tags: java, android

I would like to display an integer (from 0 to 10,000) as an icon in my android notification bar (like battery doctor). I searched in the forum and the best solution seems to be creating 10,000 drawable images for each number....It's simply impossible isn't there any other way to do that with the new versions of android ?

Comment: What makes you think that showing a 4- to 5-digit number is practical, in the available space of a `Notification` status bar icon?

Comment: how about using this library, or a similar approach to generate an image from text: https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable

Comment: thank you Sam Dozor I'll try it asap